# List element not found in pandas dataframe although existent

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, indexing

I am not after finding an element in a dataframe based on a list element, as has been discussed in various questions, I just want to know if the list element is an entry in a specific df column.

What is absolutely odd to me is the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['cmp_1', 'a'],
    ['cmp_2', 'b'],
    ['cmp_3', 'c']
]
columns = ['myID', 'content']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
print(df)

d = {
    #'1)  ':cmp_1, # error: cmp_1 not defined
    '2)  ':'cmp_1',
    '3)  ':'some'
}

for k,v in d.items():
    print(k, v in df['myID'])

# counter test
print('counter test')
print(df[df['myID'] == 'cmp_1'])
```

Output:

```py
  myID content
0  cmp_1       a
1  cmp_2       b
2  cmp_3       c
2)   False
3)   False
counter test
    myID content
0  cmp_1       a
```

The result for test `2)` is `False`, checking whether the string `'cmp_1'` is in the df. You can however clearly see in the counter test, that said string is indeed in the specified column.
Has anybody an explanation to that?

And coming back to my inital question: is there an elegant way of
a) determining, whether a list element (string) is in a specified df column
b) collecting all these list elements.

I was going with a for loop on the list but stumbled over above mentioned problem, which I think is an interesting matter in itself. My second thought was doing `df['myID'].to_numpy()` and then doing the search, but naaa... there has to be a *nice* way.

Comment: try test `'4)':1,` and you get `True` because `... in df['myID']` doesn't check values in column `'myID'` but indexes. Code `v in df['myID']` and `df['myID'] == v` doesn't work the same.

Comment: Thanks, but I kinda figured that. But why does `v in df['myID']`  **not** look for a value in `df['myID']`. That seems absolutely unintuitive and even stupid! I really read pandas docs a lot, but I haven't found the right part apparently...

Comment: Btw: you're right - your proposed test 4) returns `True` :)

Comment: `in` and `==` are different functions, they may have different code and it seems they was created for different purpose. `df['myID']` gives `Series` which is rather like `dictionary`, not `list` and in normal dictionary when you use `if name in dictionary` then it check keys, not values - and in `Series` you have indexes as keys.